# Unable to get view handle in clearcase

Tags: clearcase

We had a Disaster recovery(DR) exercise, as part of which we had transferred the mastership of VOB from replica in Primary server to the replica in DR server.

Once this was done, the users connected through CCRC to the DR server and created views and performed some dummy file creation/labelling/checkout/checkin operations.

Later we transferred the mastership of VOBs back to the replica in primary server.

Users disconnected from the same view and updated their URL to point to that of Primary server and connected again.

But when they tried to perform check-outs with the same view, they got the error "

```
Unable to find view by uuid:336e2 etc
Unable to find view handle
```

Why could this be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be happening it the registry server (which includes the `rgy/view_tag` and `rgy/view_object` text files) has not been synchronized back.

This is often the case considering a DR usually involves tests which are "lost" (meaning which are not replicated back to the original environment shut off during the DR).

It is best to simply re-create those views than trying to recover them.

Comment: Can this be rectified?

Comment: @user3437212 usually no: the DR environment is generally "reset" when done. Re-creating the view is faster, easier and allows the users to get back and running again in seconds.