# Jenkins Base Clearcase Failure

Tags: jenkins, view, clearcase, radix

I've setup a build server using Jenkins and Base Clearcase plugin for source code integration. I can take daily build successfully but sometimes  I get the following error;

```
Started by user unknown or anonymous
Running as SYSTEM
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace C:\JenkinsHome\workspace\ProjectBuild
[Project_Build_View] $ cleartool lsview -cview -s
cleartool: Error: Unable to find view by uuid:caccabc2.828941b7.86a3.f1:14:88:fe:16:4f, last known at "<viewhost>:<stg_path>".
cleartool: Error: Unable to establish connection to snapshot view "caccabc2.828941b7.86a3.f1:14:88:fe:16:4f": ClearCase object not found
cleartool: Error: Cannot get view info for current view: not a ClearCase object.

FATAL: Base ClearCase failed. exit code=1
[ProjectBuild] $ cleartool lsview Project_Build_View
  Project_Build_View       \\ViewStore\\Project_Build_View.vws

[INFO] computeChangeLogBeforeCheckout = false
[INFO] computeChangeLogAfterCheckout  = true
[ProjectBuild] $ cleartool lsview Project_Build_View
  Project_Build_View       \ViewStore\\Project_Build_View.3.vws

[Project_Build_View] $ cleartool lsview -cview -s
cleartool: Error: Unable to find view by uuid:caccabc2.828941b7.86a3.f1:14:88:fe:16:4f, last known at "<viewhost>:<stg_path>".
cleartool: Error: Unable to establish connection to snapshot view "caccabc2.828941b7.86a3.f1:14:88:fe:16:4f": ClearCase object not found
cleartool: Error: Cannot get view info for current view: not a ClearCase object.

FATAL: Base ClearCase failed. exit code=1
The view directory is not linked to any view tag. Removing it using OS delete.
[ProjectBuild] $ cleartool mkview -snapshot -tag Project_Build_View -stgloc -auto Project_Build_View
cleartool: Error: A registry entry already exists for "Project_Build_View".

FATAL: Base ClearCase failed. exit code=1
java.io.IOException: cleartool did not return the expected exit code. Command line="mkview -snapshot -tag Project_Build_View -stgloc -auto Project_Build_View", actual exit code=1
    at hudson.plugins.clearcase.HudsonClearToolLauncher.run(HudsonClearToolLauncher.java:152)
    at hudson.plugins.clearcase.ClearToolExec.mkview(ClearToolExec.java:563)
    at hudson.plugins.clearcase.action.SnapshotCheckoutAction.createView(SnapshotCheckoutAction.java:184)
    at hudson.plugins.clearcase.action.SnapshotCheckoutAction.cleanAndCreateViewIfNeeded(SnapshotCheckoutAction.java:128)
    at hudson.plugins.clearcase.action.BaseSnapshotCheckoutAction.checkout(BaseSnapshotCheckoutAction.java:64)
    at hudson.plugins.clearcase.AbstractClearCaseScm.checkout(AbstractClearCaseScm.java:390)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1205)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1853)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:427)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Could you please help me to resolve this issue ? What is the cause this problem ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

I have seen such an error message ("`Unable to find view by uuid`") in case of:

- an uncomplete deliver (often in a [multi-site environment](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/after-posting-deliver-remote-site-issuing-deliver-status-reports-error-unable-find-view-uuid), or a [CCRC one](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/failure-complete-posted-deliver-started-ccrc))
- a view registry [not properly synchronized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29193773/6309)
- an [albd issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1207516/6309)

Make sure of the account used for Jenkins when it executes this job, a do a `cleardoctor` to check how it (Jenkins) perceives its ClearCase environment, to spot any discrepancies between it (Jenkins) execution environment and your current user session.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the reply. For the first three possible causes, I do not have access to IBM Clearcase servers as developer. Is there any indirect way to check them ?                   I also searched "cleardoctor" on the internet but couldn't find anything useful. Could you please help me about how to check Jenkins user perceiving ClearCase environment ?

Comment: @Cranberriess_ See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.dev.doc/topics/ccdoctor/t_start_ccdoctor.htm